# Error in the installation of Ionic Framework on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, ionic-framework

I need your help in the resolution of this issue, please.
The message is showing when typing the command `$ionic`:

```
$ionic ...
=========================================================================
**events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)**
```

Comment: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/windows-and-ionic-cli/7236

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to sass setup in the project, In my case I had to change below line

```
"gulpStartupTasks": [
  "sass",
  "watch"
]
```

to

```
"gulpStartupTasks": []
```

in ionic.project file

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/4398734-adding-gulpstartuptasks-to-ionic-project-causes-ionic-serve-to-error-on-1-2-5

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem with you.(HATE WINDOWS!)

And happily I found the solution about this, please follow the steps below:

1. Open C:\Users\*YOUR USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\cordova.js
2. Goto line 40, and
   replace
    `var cordovaCmd = spawn('cordovaz', cmdArgs);`
   to
    `var cordovaCmd = spawn(process.platform === "win32" ? "cordova.cmd" : "cordova", cmdArgs);`
3. try `ionic run android` again!